# SQL formatting using VBA code

Tags: vba

I'm very new to VBA macro coding and I have a problem. I wrote a Macro VBA code for automatically generating SQL queries to a text file.the output what I am getting is unformatted SQL.how to convert code into well formatted script using VBA code.
Please help me 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not how you ask questions on SO. Please take 30 min and read this carefully [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how to convert code into well formatted script using VBA code.

Sorry, VBA does not include a built-in SQL pretty printer. You will have to implement one yourself (not an easy task, far beyond the scope of a SO question) or use an external tool or library.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.it will be great if you help me how to implement one using VBA code..